# Script to make content entry into a text file

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wsh

How do I include some "text" into a .txt format file without opening the same via a script on Windows?

Comment: echo This is My Text >> myText.txt? - Really though, this seems more suited to StackOverflow - voting to close/move...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I will give you an all PowerShell answer. You can use [Add-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849859.aspx) or [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Content) cmdlets.

Set-Content overwrites the target file and Add-Content appends to the file.

```
Set-Content -Value "Test1" -Path C:\Scripts\Scratch\test.txt
Add-Content -Value "Test" -Path C:\Scripts\Scratch\test.txt
```

Or, you can also use [Out-File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Out-File).

```
"Test" | Out-File -FilePath C:\Scripts\Scratch\test.txt -Append
```

Answer (score 5):

The command you need is `echo` (alias of [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output) - use [Get-Alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Get-Alias) to get the list):

```
 echo Text >> textFile.txt
```

[This link](http://commandwindows.com/command1.htm) should prove helpful in learning Windows commands.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the sample code to create and add content into a text file:

```
$text = Hello World

# This is to create file:
$text | Set-Content MyFile.txt

# Or
$text | Out-File MyFile.txt

# Or
$text > MyFile.txt


# This is to write into a file or append to the text file created:
$text | Add-Content MyFile.txt

# Or
$text | Out-File MyFile.txt -Append

# Or
$text >> MyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it interactively from a standard Windows command prompt (typing the content in at the keyboard), you can use the following:

```
copy con c:\temp\file.txt
```

Then you can just start typing.  To finish, just hit Ctrl+Z and ENTER, like so:

```
Hello world!
Goodbye...^Z
        1 file(s) copied.
```

To view the file, use:

```
type c:\temp\file.txt
```

You should see the following output:

```
Hello world!
Goodbye...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) cmdlet should work fine for you.

Answer (score -4):

```
$com1 = New-Object PSobject  # Task 1
$com2 = New-Object PSobject  # Task 1
$com3 = New-Object PSobject  # Task 1

$com1 | Add-Member noteproperty -name user -value jindpal                      # Task 2
$com1 | Add-Member noteproperty -name code -value IT01                         # Task 2
$com1 | Add-Member scriptmethod ver {[system.Environment]::oSVersion.Version}  # Task 3

$com2 | Add-Member noteproperty -name user -value singh                        # Task 2
$com2 | Add-Member noteproperty -name code -value IT02                         # Task 2
$com2 | Add-Member scriptmethod ver {[system.Environment]::oSVersion.Version}  # Task 3

$com3 | Add-Member noteproperty -name user -value dhanoa                       # Task 2
$com3 | Add-Member noteproperty -name code -value IT03                         # Task 2
$com3 | Add-Member scriptmethod ver {[system.Environment]::oSVersion.Version}  # Task 3

$arr += $com1, $com2, $com3  # Task4

Write-Host  "Windows version of computer 1 is: "$com1.ver()  # Task 3
Write-Host  "User name of computer 1 is: "$com1.user         # Task 6
Write-Host  "Code of computer 1 is: "$com1,code              # Task 5

Write-Host  "Windows version of computer 2 is: "$com2.ver()  # Task 3
Write-Host  "User name of computer 2 is: "$com2.user         # Task 6
Write-Host  "Windows version of computer 3 is: "$com3.ver()  # Task 3

Write-Host  "User name of computer 3 is: "$com1.user         # Task 6
Write-Host  "Code of computer 3 is: "$com3,code              # Task 5

Read-Host
```

Comment: $arr =@("jind",12, "singh")
write-host $arr[1]
read-host
$arr += "reza"
write-host $arr[3]
read-host
write-host $arr[$arr.length-1]
read-host
$arr = $arr -ne $arr[1]
write-host $arr
read-host

foreach ($i in $arr)
{write-host $i}

Comment: $room = Read-Host “Enter a room number:”
get-content computers.txt | where {$_ -match "B108"}
$newcontents = get-content computers.txt | where {$_ -match "B108"}

Comment: An explanation would be in order.